# Codeigniter HMVC Structure

Tags: structure, codeigniter-3, hmvc

**What is the proper way to do this?**

This is what I did:

```
-Module

--Admin // Module

---Controllers

----dashboard.php

----users.php
```

or

```
-Module

--dashboard // Module

---Controllers

----dashboard.php

--users // Module

---Controllers

----users.php
```

I did this because I want to separate admin from user module.

I am so sorry for asking such a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Codeigniter HMVC, the structure is something like this :

[image: Codeigniter HMVC Tree]

Source :

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

https://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/06/28/a-modular-approach-to-web-development/